# Using dlsym in c++ without extern "C"

Tags: c++, g++

I have a system in which I give the user a function prototype and the user has to implement it. Now, I compile this file using g++ and load it dynamically using dlopen and dlsym to process it further. Now, I read here:

[c++ dlopen mini-howto](http://www.isotton.com/devel/docs/C++-dlopen-mini-HOWTO/C++-dlopen-mini-HOWTO.html#loadingfunctions)

that to load c++ functions we have to use extern "C" before the function. Now, the problem is, I do not want to show the user how things are working. I do not want to show the user extern "C" before the function.

Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: Hide the `extern "C"` somewhere in a preprocessor macro?  Or modify the source that they give you to include the `extern "C"`?  You haven't given us enough information to answer this, but it shouldn't be difficult at all. Seeing some code would help to understand what you're doing.

Comment: Yes, just give the mangled name instead of the "C" style name. Something like `Z4MyFunc_iii` or whatever it may be, instead of `MyFunc`.  But I don't see why you can't say "You need this magic incatantation `extern "C"` in front of your function".

Comment: You don't want to let the user *see* `extern "C"` or you don't want to require the user to write it himself? What's really going on here? This question is very vague.

Comment: What? You want to give the user a prototype to implement, but you do not want to show the *correct* prototype? Why are you willing to show, say, the return type, but not the `extern "C"`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [mangled C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B) name directly.

If you have e.g. a C++ function `void my_plugin(int foo)` , the C++ compiler will mangle that name.
Once you know the mangled function name, you can use dlopen() on that name.

e.g.

```
# nm libmyplugin.so |grep my_plugin
00000000 T _Z9my_plugini
```

So here our function is named _Z9my_plugini , and you could do

```
 func = dlsym(handle, "_Z9my_plugini");
```

Traditionally different compilers could mangle the name in different ways, so this could be quite fragile, thoug these days most C++ compilers will aggree opon a standard way of mangling the names on a given platform.

However your users will be programmers, and they would normally have an understanding of exposing an entry to a dynamically loaded library as `extern "C"`

Comment: 1. No, there isn't a standard mangling scheme, or any push to converge on one. 2. New C++11 and C++1y features mean mangling schemes tend to *diverge*. 3. He said the motivation is to avoid exposing internal workings to the user. Not sure what that means, but this isn't it.

Comment: @Potatoswatter While I agree that using a C++ mangled name like this is silly, there are platforms that have a C++ ABI that standardises the name mangling.

Comment: There are platform-wide ABIs, but none that cover all the features currently specified. Even GCC prints error messages "internal error: sorry, cannot mangle this" for some cases.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using C++, why don't you export only one (or two) functions that will simply return a pointer to some kind of pure virtual class, say `IMyModule`? The one (or two) exported `extern "C"` functions would be something similar to `extern "C" IMyModule * create_instance_IMyModule();` (and `extern "C" void delete_instance_IMyModule(IMyModule const *);`).

Comment: ... and you can provide a macro like `EXPORT_MODULE` or some such which will expand to these and the user won't have to care. They'll implement the interface and write the macro in the implementation file and that will be it.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to `extern "C"` before each declaration is to use the block-style syntax:

```
extern "C" {

void my_callback();
int other_functionality( foo * );

}
```

Often the `extern "C" {` and closing brace `}` are wrapped in macros, which are conditional on the `__cplusplus` built-in macro, so the header can also be used from pure C. This also encapsulates the part you find objectionable.

In any case, I don't see what the big deal is. If the user can write in C++, they should be competent to enclose their C interface function prototypes in `extern "C"` when the library documentation tells them to.

Comment: The first solution you gave does not work. We are using the same compiler.

Comment: @Rishi You mean you are *not* using the same compiler?

Comment: No, we ARE using the same compiler.

Comment: @Rishi Sorry, I got distracted and forgot that the symbol name isn't getting handled by the linker. That paragraph was just extraneous.