# Undefined symbol for dlsym in C++

Tags: c++, dlopen, dlsym

I have one C++ program which I want to load into my current running C++ program. Following are the snippet

**File : a.cpp**

```
    #include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;

    void abc() { 
      cout << "This is abc" << endl;
    }
```

**File : mainFile.cpp**

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    #include <dlfcn.h>

    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
      system("g++ -fpic -shared -ldl -o a.so a.cpp"); 
      void *lib = dlopen("./a.so", RTLD_NOW);
       if (!lib) {
         printf("dlopen failed: %s\n", dlerror());
         return 1;
      }
      void (*f)();
      f = (void (*)()) dlsym(lib, "abc");
      if (f) {
          f();
      } else {
          printf("dlsym for f1 failed: %s\n", dlerror());
      }

      dlclose(lib);
      return 0;
    }
```

I am compiling with the following commands

```
    g++ -w mainFile.cpp -ldl -o mainFile && ./mainFile
```

Output:

```
    dlsym for f1 failed: ./a.so: undefined symbol: abc
```

Please help.

I am compiling in Ubuntu 16.04 with g++ version g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609

**OBSERVATION**
What's strange is, when I have the above a.cpp file as a.c and with only stdio.h as header and also with a -fpermissive flag, the program compiles and I get the output as `This is abc`. I do not understand why the CPP version fails. The reason I cannot use CPP (or rather hesitate to go the .C route) is that my project requires OOPS concept and I have to use classes in the library file. The above example is only to simplify the objective.
Note: I have followed the following references but none helped.

1. [Can you dynamically compile and link/load C code into a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56829292/can-you-dynamically-compile-and-link-load-c-code-into-a-c-program)
2. [undefined reference to `dlopen' since ubuntu upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926466/undefined-reference-to-dlopen-since-ubuntu-upgrade)
3. [C dlsym undefined symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35896521/c-dlsym-undefined-symbol)

Comment: try to define `void abc` as `extern "C"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041866/what-is-the-effect-of-extern-c-in-c

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096596/using-dlsym-in-c-without-extern-c

Comment: Thank you, everyone. using extern "C" worked.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ names are mangled, that is, the name of the symbol in the library is not just `abc`. Instead it has additional characters (decoration) that describe the arguments etc. of that function. That is why you don't find the function by the name `abc`.

You have two options:

1. Look up the mangled name (which may be difficult/non-portable since mangling depends on the compiler).
2. Declare function `abc()` as `extern "C" { void abc(); }`. This requests C-linkage for the function and thus prevents name mangling.

See also the many pointers you got in the comments.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel !! Option 1 did not seem practical for anything larger than practice exercise. I tried option 2 and it worked.